# Why does isdigit always return false?

Tags: c

I cannot get `isdigit` to work. Here is some of my code.

```
void input(int *array, int size) {
    int x;
    printf("Give me ten numbers. \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        do {
            printf("Array[%d]: ", i);
            scanf("%d", &x);
            scanf("%*[^\n]");
        } while (!isdigit(x));
        array[i] = x;
    }
}
```

The aim of this program is to read an integer from the keyboard with `scanf` (which is no problem). If the input is not a number, it should repeat the while loop, until the user gives a number. With `isdigit`, you should be able to identify if a character is an integer or not. It returns 1 if integer, 0 if not. At least, that should be the case. In this code it always returns 0.

Comment: What does "not work" mean, to you? Please describe the outcome, and the expected outcome. Also, remember that I/O can fai: you should check the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: What is the aim of this code?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: `scanf("%*[^\n]"); // fflush does not work on Macs. This is an alternative.` does not scan in a `'\n'`.  So any <Enter key> will only be read with `scanf("%c", &x);`.  Recommend using `fgets(buffer, ...)` for user input and then scan the buffer for the desired text

Answer (score 1):

I cannot understand what are you trying to do. First if you need the integer number of a charachter you should leave the value '0' so

```
c-'0'.
```

Then rather than use scanf, if you should just get a charachter much better getchar()
to flush just

```
 while(getchar()!='\n')
              ;
```

Than if you do not want use the proper *scanf("%d",&int_variable);* you have to build a function to rebuild the number, it means take the charachter, leave '0' and multiply by ten at each following charachter.

Answer (score 0):

Sweet problem!! `isdigit` take argument a single character(ASCII Value) and determine whether the character is digit or not . [so, it will work for signal digit].

first, as `isdigit` take argument a single character, if you pass the digit as argument then it will say "NO IT IS NOT NUMBER". You should pass ASCII value of single digit number as argument of 
`isdigit`.

I mean, '1' != 1

'1' is equal to 1+'0' which is ASCII value of character '1'.

Solution 1: [It will work for single digit]

```
void input(int *array, int size) {
    printf("Give me ten numbers. \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int x;
        do {
            x = 'a'; //bcz if user enter a character, scanf will not able to take the value, so, x will hold the previous value
            printf("Array[%d]: ", i);
            scanf("%d", &x);
            scanf("%*[^\n]"); // fflush does not work on Macs. This is an alternative. [I don't know about the line, I copied from you.]
        } while (!isdigit(x+'0')); //converting the value to character

        array[i] = x;
    }
}
```

Solution 2 : (For pro) :p single line code :)

```
void input(int *array, int size) {
    printf("Give me ten numbers. \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        while( printf("array[%d] = ",i) && !scanf("%d",&array[i]) && !scanf("%*[^\n]")); // it will give same result.
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution 1 is added.

Comment: Solution 2 added.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: 'fflush(stdin)'  is works fine is Windows & Linux. I don't about MACs

Comment: Thank you! I think that this is what I am looking for!

Comment: "works fine" is not an answer to "undefined behavior". It is still undefined behavior, and you still should not be using it, even if it *appears* to "work fine".

Comment: Don't why, people marked my ans as down vote. But it works fine. :(

Comment: Then, upper one is fine. :) @cody Gray

Comment: @Rogier Reerink, if you satisfied with my code , pls mark as ans. :)

Comment: @RitwickDey, I haven't been able to get it to work actually.

Comment: Do you not get how it is working? Or program is not working?

Comment: If you are not getting the solution 2, just tell me. I'll make a simple for you